# How to match question mark "?" as regexp on nginx.conf location

Tags: regex, nginx

I'd like to match question mark "?" as regexp on nginx.conf location.

For example, a URL pattern which I'd like to match is /something?foo=5 or /something?bar=8 (parameter only changeable).

Because nginx adopts [RCPE](http://wiki.nginx.org/InstallOptions#Notes), I can write the location on nginx.conf as follows:

```
location ~ ^/something\?.* {
}
```

The above doesn't match the URL pattern.  How can I do that?

Also, the following is not my expectation.

```
location ~ ^/something?.* {
}
```

It'll match /something_foo_bar_buzz that I don't expect.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

nginx [location block doesn't match query string](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) at all. So it's impossible.

> Location
>
> This directive allows different configurations depending on the URI.

In nginx, there is a built-in variable [$uri](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri), which the location block is matched against. For example, give a request

```
http://www.example.com/app/login.php?username=xyz&password=secret
```

the $uri value is this string:

```
 /app/login.php
```

and the query_string is stored in nginx variable  [$args](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args):

```
username=xyz&password=secret
```

To do something wrt. query string, you can do something like

```
if ($args ~ username=xyz) {
   # do something for requests with this query string
}
```

But be careful, [IF is Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)