# How to create a right RegExp in nginx which will match "?item_id="

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config

How is it necessary to change pattern in `if ($request_uri ~ \?item_id=) {...}` in order to match ?item_id= as a whole string? In regex tester `\?item_id=` works properly but in nginx config not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match question mark "?" as regexp on nginx.conf location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713934/how-to-match-question-mark-as-regexp-on-nginx-conf-location)

Comment: Your regex is working properly. There are some other things in your config that doesn't work as you expected. Clarify your question, maybe it worth to post your config and explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>In Nginx, the request $uri won't contain the query string.</strike>

That means that using http://example.com/foo/bar?gee=123, only "/foo/bar" is part of the request URI.

So, matching a question mark is basically impossible on `$uri`.

Edit: Testing on the arguments should be done using $`args`.

Comment: You are wrong, nginx `$request_uri` built-in variable contains full original request URI with query arguments. But the locations are matched against an `$uri` variable, not the `$request_uri` one. An `$uri` variable contains the normalized request URI **without** query part.